# Version maintenance in firebase hosting while using both firebase CLI and REST API for hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Our app hosted on firebase hosting is currently updated via firebase CLI. However, our app may get a feature where a user can create some custom static web files and upload a zip file containing those files to our site, after which these files are available as part of the site. (like a wiki/news article). For example: if a user uploads a zip file file which contains an index.html and some images that are linked to the html file, then the site will get updated with these materials and will show them at: oursite.com/username/somearticle/index.html

Through info gathered via this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/api-deploy) , it appears that using the Hosting REST API would be able to get the job done. However I have a few questions about the functionality offered by this solution:

1. To start using the API, we firstly need an access token to authenticate and authorize API requests. Is there a way to get this token for a standard user who's logged in to our site using firebase authentication?
2. It says in [this part](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/api-deploy#specify-files) of the article that you need the list of all currently existing files and new files in order to update the site. How do I access the list of files that are currently a part of the site?
3. On a similar note like the above question, we may need to update the app functionality from time to time and those updates are done via the CLI. How do I ensure that these functionality updates don't overwrite updates made by the user? In other words, is there a way to merge updates into the hosting site using CLI commands?

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen. Your answers helped me figure out what to do which is as follows: 1. User uploads a  zip file 2. It gets decompressed and the files are uploaded to cloud storage 3. A cloud function gets executed when these files are uploaded that makes them open to the public.

Answer (score 1):

1. Firebase Authentication users don't have enough privileges to deploy to hosting. The users will need to be **collaborators** on the Firebase project, which means they'll need to have a Google account.
2. I recommend checking out my Gist that shows how to [deploy a single files](https://gist.github.com/puf/e00c34dd82b35c56e91adbc3a9b1c412), which does something quite similar that what you're trying to accomplish. It gets the list of existing files (and their hashes) in [this code fragment](https://gist.github.com/puf/e00c34dd82b35c56e91adbc3a9b1c412#file-deployfile-js-L43-L50).

Comment: Hmm, so is there  a way through firebase that users can upload their zip files containing their static web files which we can then decompress and place somewhere which can be accessible publicly? I tried doing this manually in firebase storage but the html file doesnt recognize the paths for the other assets.

Comment: You could create a Cloud Function that triggers when they upload the file(s) to Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 1):

"When a user uploads a file" doesn't exactly sound alike "version control" to me ...
better use [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories) and add a Build Trigger, which deploys to Firebase Hosting.
Here it's explained: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase

I mean, how else would you'd be able to keep a version history? And if you really want to upload something, just upload, unzip, also commit to git. HTML files are perfectly suitable for that.
The general idea is to have a continuous version history, which automatically deploys itself on change.